# Having some problems with glyphicons from bootstrap 3.3.5 in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, glyphicons

I can't manage to find an answer at my problem. Glyphicons still don't work in Firefox. Firefox only.

What I do for example : `<li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>    Home</a></li>`

In my .css file :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
```

src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

Comment: I've never had any problems with glyphicons in Firefox. Why not download the file and store it in your folder instead of using `src` ? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.0.0.zip

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think it's the common way to use them? Beside, the problem only happens with firefox. Why?

Comment: It is strange, I have just tried your code in my Firefox and it works. Have you tried in jsfiddle to see if it works? http://jsfiddle.net/ztm1cbpw/

Comment: I just tested now.  Same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have the required CDN's? I have just added the the required css and js files to the jsfiddle you posted and it works. i.e. `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js` https://jsfiddle.net/d7na1qb8/1/

Comment: I tried it too on my pc and using https://www.browserling.com/ and it worked.

Comment: Works fine on my PC. Must be something else your end.

Comment: Have I helped? @AlphA-Fr

Comment: Sure kjehfiuh, thanks for your help, I finally get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7na1qb8/) you posted for the problem, it appears you are missing the required CDN. After I included these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script
```

It [displayed](https://jsfiddle.net/d7na1qb8/1/) the glyphicons. Make sure you have these included in your page and it should work. :)

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I  don't understand why. I already had wrote this line in the file :  <link href="../bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Bootstrap is mysterious like that. If something doesn't work, make sure the CDN links are correct first. I have found that out myself many times :). Glad it works now though! Did you say that it worked in other browsers?